# Reference to javascript object apparently returning different values in different places with no modifications in between

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using a variable twice within a function but it returns different values even though I'm making no modifications to it.

This is happening within a form component developed with Vue.js (v2) which dispatches a Vuex action. I think this has nothing to do with Vue/Vuex per se, but it's important to understand part of the code.

Here is the relevant piece of code from my component

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      product: {
        code: '',
        description: '',
        type: '',
        productImage: [], 
        productDocs: {},
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {

    ...mapActions(['event']),

    save() {
      console.log("this.product:", this.product)
      const valid = this.$refs.form.validate() // this validates the form
      console.log("this.product:", this.product)
      if (valid) {
        try {
          this.event({
            action: 'product/addProduct',
            data: this.product
          })
        }
        finally {
          this.close()  
        }
      }
    },

// other stuff
```

and a small piece of code for the vuex action "event"

```
event: async ({ dispatch }, event) => {
      const time = new Date()
      const evid = `${Date.now()}|${Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)}`
      console.log(`Preparing to dispatch... Action: ${event.action} | data: ${JSON.stringify(event.data)} | Event ID: ${evid}`)

      // enriching event
      event.evid = evid;
      event.timestamp = time;
      event.synced = 0

      // Push user event to buffer
      try {
        await buffer.events.add(event)

      } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Error writing event into buffer. Action ${event.action} | evid: ${evid} `)
      }

      // dispatch action 
      try {
        await dispatch(event.action, event)
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error dispatching action: ${event.action} | data: ${event.data}\n${err.stack || err}`)
        window.alert('Could not save. Try again. \n' + err + `\n Action: ${event.action} | data: ${event.data}`)
      }
    },
```

The problem is with `this.product`. I've placed the several `console.log` to check out the actual values because it wasn't working as expected. The logs from the `save()` functions return `undefined`, but within the `event` function (a vuex action) the values are as expected, as shown in the console logs:

When I log `this.product` in the `save()` function. Both logs are the same.
[image: console.log(this.product)]

When I log the `event` in the vuex action, it shows that `event.data` is actually the product.
[image: console.log from <code>event</code> function]

I must be doing something terribly wrong here, but I'm totally blind to it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is not very clear. Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Try to minimize links to pictures.

Comment: Part of this may be because of that tiny `i` next to the opened product. If you hover over it, it says that "the object has been evaluated just now", which means it evaluates what is in the object when you open the object, which is way after executing the action. Consider adding a `debugger` statement after the first log and either inspect the object directly, or open the log then. You will likely see a different payload. Whatever is changing the product may very well happen after the event somewhere.

Comment: This looks like a scoping problem - try defining save as `save: () => {` instead.

Comment: @dezfowler Vue handles the scoping automagically. So writing `save: () => {` will break the code scope.

Comment: Can you provide the whole code of `event` action?

Comment: Where else do you use `this.product`? Is it possible that `this.$refs.form.validate()` changes the value unexpectedly?

Comment: @Yong Quan: tried logging before and after the validation. No change.
@EvilArthas: edited the question with full code for the `event` method just for reference.

Answer (score 0):

@Sumurai8: thanks for editing the question and for the hint.

> Part of this may be because of that tiny i next to the opened product.
>   If you hover over it, it says that "the object has been evaluated just
>   now", which means it evaluates what is in the object when you open the
>   object, which is way after executing the action. [...] Whatever is
>   changing the product may very well happen after the event somewhere.

It actually helped me find the solution.

Basically within the `this.close` function called in the `finally` statement of the `save()` function, I was resetting the form and thus `this.product`, which was used solely to hold the form data. So at evaluation time, the object had undefined properties, while the `event` function managed to output to the console before the reset. However at the end the store would not get updated as expected (that's how I noticed the issue), because the `event` function and the action called within it are asynchronous and so the value got reset before the actual mutation of the vuex store.

Logging `JSON.stringify(this.product)` outputted the right value even within the `save()` method. I used that to create a more robust copy of the data and passed that to the event function as follows:

```
this.event({
  action: 'product/addProduct',
  data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.product))
})
```

Now everything works like a charme.

Comment: @Sumurai8 if you want to repost your comment as answer I can flag it as the solution.